# tree traversal: If c is children of a, should i list first c then a when getting in inorder traversal

Tags: discrete-mathematics, trees

[image: Tree]

I am trying to list preorder, inorder and postorder traversal of the tree above using flags but I am not sure with my answer particularly on inorder. I am confused if I shall list first the children then its parent or parent then children e.g c and a

Can you also check if my answer is right?

```
preorder = a,b,e,j,k,f,g,l,m,c,d,h,n,i,o,q,r,s,p
inorder = j,e,k,f,b,l,g,m,c,a,n,h,d,q,r,o,s,i,p
postorder = j,k,e,f,l,m,g,b,c,n,h,q,r,s,o,p,i,d,a
```

Comment: I've never seen 'inorder' defined for more than 2 children. In binary trees inorder means parent is visited between its children, for more than two you need a more specific definition of 'inorder' to decide between `f,b` and `b,f` or between `a,c` and `c,a`.

Comment: You may also want to see answers at StackOverflow [search: inorder traversal "non binary" tree](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=inorder+traversal+%22non+binary%22+tree), e.g. this one: [In-order tree traversal for non-binary trees](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23778489/in-order-tree-traversal-for-non-binary-trees) (no relevant results at Math SE).